# How to submit form with multiple inputs with the same name

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form with three input fields and function to add new row:

```
<form ng-submit="">
 <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="person in persons">    
  <input type="text" ng-model="username">
  <input type="text" ng-model="house">
  <input type="text" ng-model="points">
 </fieldset>
 <button ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And then I try to print data and its empty.

```
<div id="choicesDisplay">
  {{ persons }}
</div>
```

js part:

```
$scope.persons = [];
$scope.addNewChoice = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.persons.length + 1;
  $scope.persons.push({
    'username': "",
    'house': "",
    'points': "",
  });
};
$scope.removeChoice = function() {
  var lastItem = $scope.persons.length-1;
  $scope.persons.splice(lastItem);
};
```

How is it possible to submit form as an array? I cant use `username[]`. Thank you

Comment: You may use `ng-model="person.username"` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to user `<input type="text" ng-model="person.username">`

html:

```
<form ng-submit="">
     <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="person in persons">    
      <input type="text" ng-model="person.username">
      <input type="text" ng-model="person.house">
      <input type="text" ng-model="person.points">
     </fieldset>
     <button ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

And then I try to print data and its empty.

```
<div id="choicesDisplay">
  {{ persons }}
</div>
```

js part:

```
$scope.persons = [];
$scope.addNewChoice = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.persons.length + 1;
  $scope.persons.push({
    'username': "",
    'house': "",
    'points': "",
  });
};
$scope.removeChoice = function() {
  var lastItem = $scope.persons.length-1;
  $scope.persons.splice(lastItem);
};
```